# php, string to int

Tags: php

how convert from string to int?

```
    If i print $width_s, get: 1024 
If i print $width, get 0.
```

How convert string to integer(number) ?

```
$width_s = '<script language="javascript">document.write(screen.width)</script>';
$width = (int)$width_s;

var_dump($width);
```

Comment: Are you trying to just return the screen width?  Right now you're trying to cast a string that's full of text into an integer in the example you've given... what are you expecting the integer output to be?

Comment: How can you get 1024 printing $width_s??? You can't mix server-side and client-side code this way.

Comment: `(int)"anything that doesn't start with a number"` always evaluates to `0`. What are you actually trying to accomplish? Getting the `screen.width`??

Comment: but i get " $width_s" this value. If you don't believe, try my code :)

Comment: This is one of the reasons why I ignored the `php` tag. (Not the question or the answers, but these comments.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert a string to a number in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529656/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-a-number-in-php)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

PHP is executed on the server side, while javascript is executed on the client side; if you want a value from javascript to be sent to PHP, you will need to write up some kind of script to pass the data, via AJAX, GET, etc.

**edit**: data<s>base</s> != data

Answer (score 2):

You can use the php function intval($string).
Learn about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php).

Answer (score 0):

see:

http://www.php.net/intval

The problem with your code is that its a string with characters that aren't numbers, so casting to int isn't possible. Intval returns only the numeric part of a given string.