# How do I convert a string to a number in PHP?

Tags: php, casting, type-conversion

I want to convert these types of values, `'3'`, `'2.34'`, `'0.234343'`, etc. to a number. In JavaScript we can use `Number()`, but is there any similar method available in PHP?

```
Input             Output
'2'               2
'2.34'            2.34
'0.3454545'       0.3454545
```

Comment: Reader beware: there is no real answer to this question :(

Comment: @MatthieuNapoli The answer is that usually Php figures it out for you - one of the perks of a dynamic type system.

Comment: With all the chains of uncertainty and 'usually'.

Comment: I think what I meant 5 years ago is that there is not **a single function** that takes the string and returns a proper `int` or `float` (you usually don't want a `float` when an `int` is given).

Comment: @MatthieuNapoli I am glad you clarified your point to mean there is more than one way to skin a cat, rather than there is no way to do this.  Casting is very important in database operations, for instance.  For example on a parameterized  PDO query, there will be a struggle sometimes for the parser to realize it is a number and not a string, and then you end up with a 0 in an integer field because you did not cast the string to an int in the parameter step.

Comment: BTW, in JavaScript, the literal integer `2` is stored internally as a [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number): "A number literal like 37 in JavaScript code is a **floating-point value, not an integer**. There is no separate integer type in common everyday use. (JavaScript now has a BigInt type, but it was not designed to replace Number for everyday uses. 37 is still a Number, not a BigInt.)"  So the only reason `Number(your_string)` does what you want in JS, is logic elsewhere that defaults to display `2` as `"2"` rather than `"2.0"`.

Answer (score 1444, accepted):

You don't typically need to do this, since PHP will coerce the type for you in most circumstances. For situations where you do want to explicitly convert the type, [*cast*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting) it:

```
$num = "3.14";
$int = (int)$num;
$float = (float)$num;
```

Comment: here the situation is bit different I want to convert any string(contains only numbers) to a general number. As U may know in javaScript we can use **parseInt()** to convert string=>int or parseFloat() to convert string=>float. but in general javaScript use Number()  to convert string => number. I want a similar method in php?

Comment: @sara AFAIK there's no built-in function for that, you'd have to create one yourself which, for example, checks if there's a `.` in the string in which case you cast it to `float`. But, again, this is unnecessary in most circumstances, a string will work just fine.

Comment: It was useful for me when I had a month number obtained from a full date string, wich I used to pull a value from a moth names array. Auto casting doesn't happen here because string indexes are valid, but not equivalent.

Comment: Depending on the context, it might not be safe to assume that `.` is the decimal point separator. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Countries_using_Arabic_numerals_with_decimal_comma

Comment: @Sara: You can also create a function for converting the string to _number_ by first casting it to integer, then to float and then comparing if both values (integer and float) are equal. If they are, you should return the value as integer, if not, then as a float. Hope you get the idea.

Comment: There are times that you need to pass the integer to file system, it is not a good idea to wait for PHP to do the conversion for you.

Comment: There's also `$num = +"3.14";`

Comment: Casting isnt' always a good way of doing it, if you don't expand on it. For example, if the original string is `99 bottles of beer on the wall`, and you cast it to int, for example, you'll end up with `99`. This could cause problems if you're relying on the casting result to be used later on. If that's the case, you should probably check `if($afterCasting == $beforeCasting) { /* do stuff */ } else { /* do some other stuff */}`

Comment: @FiddlingAway True, but be aware that `(int)'99 bottles' == '99 bottles'` is true… You'll need some better form of validation than this approach.

Comment: This will actually introduce very small errors since floating point numbers are an approximation and not an exact representation.

Answer (score 267):

There are a few ways to do so:

1. Cast the strings to numeric primitive data types:

   ```
   $num = (int) "10";
   $num = (double) "10.12"; // same as (float) "10.12";
   ```
2. Perform math operations on the strings:

   ```
   $num = "10" + 1;
   $num = floor("10.1");
   ```
3. Use [`intval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) or [`floatval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php):

   ```
   $num = intval("10");
   $num = floatval("10.1");
   ```
4. Use [`settype()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.settype.php).

Comment: Note that `(double)` is just an alias for `(float)`.

Comment: @downvoter, I don't know what's wrong with my answer. Note that I posted this before OP edited her question, however this covers the edited question as well (`$num = "10" + 1` example).

Comment: On a side note intval will return 0 if the range falls out of -2147483648 to 2147483647 in 32 bit systems

Comment: @ed-ta: pretty sure it would return min/max value instead of 0 if you pass strings to it. I.e. `intval("9999999999")==2147483647`.

Comment: But then there's no way to see the difference bewteen `intval("0")` and `intval("foo")`?

Comment: `intval` is useful because then you can use it in `array_map('intval', $arrayOfStrings);` which you can't do with casting.

Comment: Note that `"10"+1` simply causes php to call `intval` implicitly, rather than you writing it explicitly.  So it works fine, but be aware it's because of php's rules about inserting implicit conversion.

(I prefer making things explicit, myself -- it communicates to other programmers that I know I'm treating text as a number, and also PHP is famous for having ..."unexpected" corner cases, among all its rules about implicit conversions.)

Comment: instead of `$num = "10" + 1;` it's better to use `$num = "10" * 1;` since that will not change the value (neutral element of multiplication), this is essentially something like `toNumber(..)` since the final type will be determined by what is needed to convert the string "10" -> (int) 10; "10.1" -> (float) 10.1;

Comment: Regarding option 2 - since PHP 7.1 operators (+ - * / ** % << >> | & ^) expect numbers and throw a "Warning: A non-numeric value encountered" if you give them something like an empty string. So if there's a chance of that happening better use some math function like ceil or just cast.

Answer (score 95):

To avoid problems try [`intval($var)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php). Some examples:

```
<?php
echo intval(42);                      // 42
echo intval(4.2);                     // 4
echo intval('42');                    // 42
echo intval('+42');                   // 42
echo intval('-42');                   // -42
echo intval(042);                     // 34 (octal as starts with zero)
echo intval('042');                   // 42
echo intval(1e10);                    // 1410065408
echo intval('1e10');                  // 1
echo intval(0x1A);                    // 26 (hex as starts with 0x)
echo intval(42000000);                // 42000000
echo intval(420000000000000000000);   // 0
echo intval('420000000000000000000'); // 2147483647
echo intval(42, 8);                   // 42
echo intval('42', 8);                 // 34
echo intval(array());                 // 0
echo intval(array('foo', 'bar'));     // 1
?>
```

Comment: IMHO, This is the only correct answer because it is the only one that takes the radix of the numeric string into consideration.  All of the responses (even those suggesting a user-defined function) that simply use a type cast will fail if the numeric string has one or more leading zeros, and the string is NOT intended as a number with an octal base.

Comment: any idea if I want to convert "12.7896" in to `12.7896`?

Comment: use floatval() to convert a string to a float. floatval("12.7896") will return 12.7896

Comment: Why isn't this the accepted answer? As a PHP outsider I already knew that `(int)$my_str` wouldn't work since I was dealing *specifically* with strings liks `01` and `013` that I want to interpret as base 10... So I wanted a way to explicitly provide the base.

Answer (score 50):

In whatever (loosely-typed) language you can always cast a string to a number by adding a zero to it.

However, there is very little sense in this as PHP will do it automatically at the time of using this variable, and it will be cast to a string anyway at the time of output.

Note that you may wish to keep dotted numbers as strings, because after casting to float it may be changed unpredictably, due to float numbers' nature.

Comment: There are many languages where you cannot cast a string to number by adding a zero, it's usually considered to be an error rather than a valid method of casting :).

Comment: honzasp is right, for example in JavaScript `typeof('123'+0)` gives `'string'`, because `'123'+0` gives `'1230'`.

Comment: Note, in PHP is is recommended that most of the time you use === style comparisons. So if you will be comparing your data it can be very important what type it is stored in.

Comment: Note that by adding a zero you're not 'casting' in the true sense, you're basically converting.

Comment: @oriol in javascript you need to add the number to zero `0+'123'` to get `123`

Comment: There are definitely use cases for this. For example, a numeric value submitted via a web form will be transmitted as a string, but it might be desirable to store it on disk as an integer.

Comment: @JonathonWisnoski: even more important if you use < or >, as it has different meanings for numbers and strings (i.e. "10" < "2" but 10 > 2).

Comment: This is especially useful when you don't know if the string is an integer of float before hand but the difference is relevant. For example, a colour value could be between 0.0 and 1.0 or it could be between 0 and 255. Using `is_float` on a string doesn't work, but using the `+0` trick will produce a float for `'1.0'` and an integer for `'1'`, allowing you to test `is_float` later without changing the value.

Comment: "there is very little sense in this as PHP will do it automatically at the time of using this variable". Only if it knows that you want to use it as a number. This is not the case if e.g. you are stuffing it into JSON and sending it off via an API to a javascript app that expects it to be a number.

Comment: @JanŠpaček Yes, but we can apply a similar concept of casting a string to a number using a math operation. In Python, PHP and JS we can transform a string into a number multiplying the numeric string times 1. Doing it this way in PHP, '1.0' will be casted to a float and '1' to an int.

Answer (score 43):

Instead of having to choose whether to convert the `string` to `int` or `float`, you can simply add a `0` to it, and PHP will automatically convert the result to a numeric type.

```
// Being sure the string is actually a number
if (is_numeric($string))
    $number = $string + 0;
else // Let the number be 0 if the string is not a number
    $number = 0;
```

Comment: this worked for me to convert to json only numeric fields to numbers

Comment: Perfect solution that allows to convert from string to integer and float in one line without checking if it contains the separator. Great, thanks

Comment: This is the right solution, works in all cases.

Answer (score 38):

Yes, there is a similar method in PHP, but it is so little known that you will rarely hear about it. It is an arithmetic operator called "**identity**", as described here:

[Aritmetic Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php)

To convert a numeric string to a number, do as follows:

```
$a = +$a;
```

Comment: Warning: hack detected.

Comment: Hi @Greg. Did you click on the link posted here? This is what the developers said about this operator: Conversion of $a to int or float as appropriate. "Conversion", here, cannot be understood as a number-to-number conversion. Why? Because from an exclusive arithmetic point of view, this operator is absolutely useless! Multiplying any number by "+1" (the equivalent of identity function) has absolutely no effect on it. Therefore, I cannot imagine other utility for this operator than the type conversion suggested here.

Comment: @Greg - surely this is *less* of a hack, than most of the other answers. Its a built-in operator, that does exactly what was requested. (Though its probably best to first check `is_numeric`, so have a place to put code to handle strings that can't convert correctly.)

Comment: I understand that it works perfectly to use an arithmetic operator for casting, but it's really easy to miss. I think it's worth a warning.

Comment: @Greg - I agree that any time code does something that may be non-obvious to the reader, a comment is worthwhile! (Though it still isn't a *hack*, as its usage is exactly what the documentation says - though I personally would not have known that, so I would be glad to see a comment there.)

Answer (score 30):

If you want get a float for `$value = '0.4'`, but int for `$value = '4'`, you can write:

```
$number = ($value == (int) $value) ? (int) $value : (float) $value;
```

It is little bit dirty, but it works.

Comment: Possibly less dirty? `strpos($val, '.') === false ? intval($val) : floatval($val);`

Comment: @jchook Possibly dirtier because it's locale-dependent - eg '0,4' instead of '0.4'.

Comment: Good point. I suppose you could use `localeconv()['decimal_point']` instead of `'.'`. One advantage of the `strpos` solution is that it's almost 2x as fast as casting twice.

Comment: @jchook that breaks on cases like `2.1e2`, it has decimal point, but resulting number is integer

Comment: @TomášBlatný Interesting point, but I think it still works because `is_float(2.1e2) === true`

Comment: @jchook but `2.1e2 === 210`, which is not float.

Comment: @TomášBlatný No it doesn't. That evaluates to false in PHP. You may have confused "float" with "number containing a fractional part"... obviously `210.0` is a float, and in PHP `2.1e2` is a float. Try it. Float has to do with the way the number gets stored in RAM and represented as a numeric literal.

Comment: @jchook Well I based this on OP's question, where he wants integers if the number isn't decimal. Yes, that statement evaluates to false, but that was more like math representation rather than php :)

Comment: Just use the `+` identity operator: `var_dump(+'0.4', +'4')`, gives you a float and an int. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

Answer (score 25):

You can use:

```
(int)(your value);
```

Or you can use:

```
intval(string)
```

Comment: what if the entered number is '2.3456' how I get 2.3456?

Comment: the question is also about floats.

Comment: Show me 1 linefrom OP where it says float? before pass comments and down votes look at Original Post.

Comment: The example shows floats, it is asking how to convert numeric strings into numeric values (floats and integers)

Comment: First check if the number is a float with `is_float`, and if that passes then cast to with `(float)` instead of `(int)`.

Comment: @MartinvanDriel - It isn't a number. Its a string. The question is how to get *either* an int or a float result, as appropriate, from a string. Won't is_float return false for a string?

Answer (score 22):

In [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) you can use `intval(string) or floatval(string)` functions to convert strings to numbers.

Comment: no I want a common method. which means if its '5' = > it should convert to 5 and if its '2.345' => it should convert to 2.345.

Comment: NOT WORKED FOR ME IT CONVERTED "3" TO 0 ZERO.

Answer (score 22):

You can always add zero to it!

```
Input             Output
'2' + 0           2 (int)
'2.34' + 0        2.34 (float)
'0.3454545' + 0   0.3454545 (float)
```

Comment: I got this error `A non well formed numeric value encountered`. any idea?

Answer (score 15):

Just a little note to the answers that can be useful and safer in some cases.
You may want to check if the string actually contains a valid numeric value first and only then convert it to a numeric type (for example if you have to manipulate data coming from a db that converts ints to strings). You can use `is_numeric()` and then `floatval()`:

```
$a = "whatever"; // any variable

if (is_numeric($a)) 
    var_dump(floatval($a)); // type is float
else 
    var_dump($a); // any type
```

Comment: this is the first good answer here. all the above are BS and dangerous since ```
intval("4C775916") => 4``` is going to potentially cause you a nasty bug.

Answer (score 14):

If you want the numerical value of a string and you don't want to convert it to float/int because you're not sure, this trick will convert it to the proper type:

```php
function get_numeric($val) {
  if (is_numeric($val)) {
    return $val + 0;
  }
  return 0;
}

Example:
<?php
get_numeric('3'); // int(3)
get_numeric('1.2'); // float(1.2)
get_numeric('3.0'); // float(3)
?>
```

Source: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php#107326

Comment: `get_numeric(010); // int 8`  
`get_numeric('010'); // int 10`

Comment: @vralle, Octal literal `010` is parsed to integer value of 8 by php interpreter; it's not kind of conversion can be done at run time.

Answer (score 12):

Here is the function that achieves what you are looking for. First we check if the value can be understood as a number, if so we turn it into an int and a float.  If the int and float are the same (e.g., 5 == 5.0) then we return the int value.  If the int and float are not the same (e.g., 5 != 5.3) then we assume you need the precision of the float and return that value.  If the value isn't numeric we throw a warning and return null.

```
function toNumber($val) {
    if (is_numeric($val)) {
        $int = (int)$val;
        $float = (float)$val;

        $val = ($int == $float) ? $int : $float;
        return $val;
    } else {
        trigger_error("Cannot cast $val to a number", E_USER_WARNING);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

I've been reading through answers and didn't see anybody mention the biggest caveat in PHP's number conversion.

The most upvoted answer suggests doing the following:

```php
$str = "3.14"
$intstr = (int)$str // now it's a number equal to 3
```

That's brilliant. PHP does direct casting. But what if we did the following?

```php
$str = "3.14is_trash"
$intstr = (int)$str
```

Does PHP consider such conversions valid?

Apparently **yes**.

PHP reads the string until it finds first non-numerical character for the required type. Meaning that for integers, numerical characters are [0-9]. As a result, it reads `3`, since it's in [0-9] character range, it continues reading. Reads `.` and stops there since it's not in [0-9] range.

Same would happen if you were to cast to float or double. PHP would read `3`, then `.`, then `1`, then `4`, and would stop at `i` since it's not valid float numeric character.

As a result, `"million" >= 1000000` evaluates to false, but `"1000000million" >= 1000000` evaluates to `true`.

See also:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php how conversions are done while comparing

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion how strings are converted to respective numbers

Comment: This is a very good answer. I worked up a bit and wrote some tests for the same
https://tutes.in/php-caveats-int-float-type-conversion/

Comment: `is_numeric($str)` helps with this. (As shown in two of the earlier answers - so its not quite accurate that "nobody mentioned the biggest caveat" - though I see no one explained the issue in detail.)

Answer (score 9):

Alright so I just ran into this issue. My problem is that the numbers/strings in question having varying numbers of digits. Some have no decimals, others have several. So for me, using `int`, `float`, `double`, `intval`, or `floatval` all gave me different results depending on the number.

So, simple solution... divide the string by 1 server-side. This forces it to a number and retains all digits while trimming unnecessary 0's. It's not pretty, but it works.

```
"your number string" / 1

Input       Output
"17"        17
"84.874"    84.874
".00234"    .00234
".123000"   .123
"032"       32
```

Comment: What are the browsers supported with this?

Comment: This is done server side

Comment: Oh ok, but may I ask can you use this code in all browsers or some browsers?

Comment: Umm... as I've said, this code is for server-side. And the question is for PHP, which is server-side execution.

Comment: when try 

echo "3.80" / 1; 

#output  3.8

Answer (score 8):

In addition to [Boykodev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529656/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-a-number-in-php/38431673#38431673) I suggest this:

```
Input             Output
'2' * 1           2 (int)
'2.34' * 1        2.34 (float)
'0.3454545' * 1   0.3454545 (float)
```

Comment: After thinking about this a little, I can also suggest division by 1 :)

Comment: That's a point! :) By the way your solution is much better than all the **scientific notations** above. Thank you.

Comment: this solution solved my problem. In my case, `$id_cron = (string)date('YmdHi'); $target_id_cron = $id_cron - 1;` instead of $target_id_cron = (int)$id_cron - 1;

Comment: I got this error `A non well formed numeric value encountered` when I want to change string to float `$num = '12,24'  * 1`. Any suggestion?

Comment: @AgnesPalit - `PHP` is anglo-centric. Only recognizes `.` as decimal separator. Try `'12.24' * 1`.  Though personally I prefer `+ 0`. Addition instead of multiplication.

Answer (score 7):

Only multiply the number by 1 so that the string is converted to type number.

```
//String value
$string = "5.1"
if(is_numeric($string)){
  $numeric_string = $string*1;
}
```

Comment: Fair enough, but this method (and similar tricks) are already listed in the 24 other answers to this question - I don't see the value in posting it again.

Comment: for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/39832873/5411817 suggested the same trick, 3 years prior.

Comment: For the SO platform to work correctly, existing Answers should be upvoted, not duplicated. If there is a typo, either add Comment below the post, or suggest. The SO platform operates in a different way than forums do. But that is part of the value of this platform. Each platform has is strengths. You would add value, in this case, by voting. Or you could comment with additional references/links. On the otherhand, if you had an awesome, game changing explanation, that nobody else offered, you could add an new Answer, while also Upvoting and linking to the previous post.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a function I wrote to simplify things for myself:

It also returns shorthand versions of boolean, integer, double and real.

```
function type($mixed, $parseNumeric = false)
{        
    if ($parseNumeric && is_numeric($mixed)) {
        //Set type to relevant numeric format
        $mixed += 0;
    }
    $t = gettype($mixed);
    switch($t) {
        case 'boolean': return 'bool'; //shorthand
        case 'integer': return 'int';  //shorthand
        case 'double': case 'real': return 'float'; //equivalent for all intents and purposes
        default: return $t;
    }
}
```

Calling type with parseNumeric set to true will convert numeric strings before checking type.

Thus:

type("5", true) will return int

type("3.7", true) will return float

type("500") will return string

Just be careful since this is a kind of false checking method and your actual variable will still be a string. You will need to convert the actual variable to the correct type if needed. I just needed it to check if the database should load an item id or alias, thus not having any unexpected effects since it will be parsed as string at run time anyway.

**Edit**

If you would like to detect if objects are functions add this case to the switch:

```
case 'object': return is_callable($mixed)?'function':'object';
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$a = "10";

$b = (int)$a;
```

You can use this to convert a string to an int in [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP).

Comment: if the entered number is '7.2345' I can't use (int) then I have to use (float). What I need is a general solution.

Comment: You can always use double or float.

Answer (score 5):

I've found that in JavaScript a simple way to convert a string to a number is to multiply it by 1. It resolves the concatenation problem, because the "+" symbol has multiple uses in JavaScript, while the "*" symbol is purely for mathematical multiplication.

Based on what I've seen here regarding PHP automatically being willing to interpret a digit-containing string as a number (and the comments about adding, since in PHP the "+" is purely for mathematical addition), this multiply trick works just fine for PHP, also.

I have tested it, and it does work... Although depending on how you acquired the string, you might want to apply the trim() function to it, before multiplying by 1.

Comment: Of course in PHP the multiply trick works exactly the same as the addition trick - with exactly the same caveats - so there isn't any particular reason to ask computer to do a multiplication. Regardless, the cleanest solution is `$var = +$str;` -- the identity operator.

Answer (score 5):

Late to the party, but here is another approach:

```
function cast_to_number($input) {
    if(is_float($input) || is_int($input)) {
        return $input;
    }
    if(!is_string($input)) {
        return false;
    }
    if(preg_match('/^-?\d+$/', $input)) {
        return intval($input);
    }
    if(preg_match('/^-?\d+\.\d+$/', $input)) {
        return floatval($input);
    }
    return false;
}

cast_to_number('123.45');       // (float) 123.45
cast_to_number('-123.45');      // (float) -123.45
cast_to_number('123');          // (int) 123
cast_to_number('-123');         // (int) -123
cast_to_number('foo 123 bar');  // false
```

Comment: CAREFUL: This lacks handling of inputs like '.123', '123.', '1.23e6' and possibly others ('0x16', ...).

Answer (score 4):

Now we are in an era where strict/strong typing has a greater sense of importance in PHP, I use `json_decode`:

```php
$num = json_decode('123');

var_dump($num); // outputs int(123)

$num = json_decode('123.45');

var_dump($num); // outputs float(123.45)
```

Comment: JSON is not PHP

Comment: @TV-C-1-5 not sure of the point you are making? Of course JSON is not PHP. PHP provides functions to encode and decode JSON. In the same way PHP provides function to encode and decode base64 - that doesn’t mean base64 _is_ PHP.

Comment: I needed to check if POSTed value was an integer and it works perfect for that.

Answer (score 4):

```
function convert_to_number($number) {
    return is_numeric($number) ? ($number + 0) : FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
((int) $var)   ( but in big number it return 2147483647 :-) )
```

But the best solution is to use:

```
if (is_numeric($var))
    $var = (isset($var)) ? $var : 0;
else
    $var = 0;
```

Or

```
if (is_numeric($var))
    $var = (trim($var) == '') ? 0 : $var;
else
    $var = 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply you can write like this:

```
<?php
    $data = ["1","2","3","4","5"];
    echo json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
?>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Are you sure about this? This won't convert a string to a number, but an array to a JSON string

Comment: Yes, @NicoHaase if the number is in string format in an array it will convert into a number.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way:

```
$value = json_decode(json_encode($value, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK|JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION|JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES), true);
```

Using `is_*` won't work, since the `variable` is a: `string`.

Using the combination of `json_encode()` and then `json_decode()` it's converted to it's "true" form. If it's a true `string` then it would output wrong.

```
$num = "Me";
$int = (int)$num;
$float = (float)$num;

var_dump($num, $int, $float);
```

Will output: `string(2) "Me" int(0) float(0)`

Comment: No doubt true. But absurdly overkill way to solve something that already has simple solutions provided years earlier. (Just be glad you didn't write it earlier - see [very downvoted answer with same approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34191394/199364)).

Answer (score 2):

You can change the data type as follows

```
$number = "1.234";

echo gettype ($number) . "\n"; //Returns string

settype($number , "float");

echo gettype ($number) . "\n"; //Returns float
```

For historical reasons "double" is returned in case of a float.

[PHP Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.settype.php)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know in advance if you have a float or an integer,
and if the string may contain special characters (like space, €, etc),
and if it may contain more than 1 dot or comma,
you may use this function:

```
// This function strip spaces and other characters from a string and return a number.
// It works for integer and float.
// It expect decimal delimiter to be either a '.' or ','
// Note: everything after an eventual 2nd decimal delimiter will be removed.
function stringToNumber($string) {
    // return 0 if the string contains no number at all or is not a string:
    if (!is_string($string) || !preg_match('/\d/', $string)) {
        return 0;
    } 

    // Replace all ',' with '.':
    $workingString = str_replace(',', '.', $string);

    // Keep only number and '.':
    $workingString = preg_replace("/[^0-9.]+/", "", $workingString);

    // Split the integer part and the decimal part,
    // (and eventually a third part if there are more 
    //     than 1 decimal delimiter in the string):
    $explodedString = explode('.', $workingString, 3);

    if ($explodedString[0] === '') {
        // No number was present before the first decimal delimiter, 
        // so we assume it was meant to be a 0:
        $explodedString[0] = '0';
    } 

    if (sizeof($explodedString) === 1) {
        // No decimal delimiter was present in the string,
        // create a string representing an integer:
        $workingString = $explodedString[0];
    } else {
        // A decimal delimiter was present,
        // create a string representing a float:
        $workingString = $explodedString[0] . '.' .  $explodedString[1];
    }

    // Create a number from this now non-ambiguous string:
    $number = $workingString * 1;

    return $number;
}
```

Comment: Personally, I consider this dubious. Taking an arbitrary, garbage, string, and searching for a number in it, is almost certainly undesireable. Much better to do what php does by default, which is convert (most) garbage strings into "0". Reason: its more obvious what happened, if unexpected strings reach your method - you simply get 0 (unless the string starts with a valid number).

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve yes it's problematic, but there is at least this use case where I had no choice: I had to display strings contained in a (not to be modified) sheet "as is", with symbols and so on, and at the same time use the number contained in it.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. What will your answer do, if there are multiple numbers scattered throughout the string?  Is this approach useful for code that converts a phone number to only the digits?  E.g. user enters `(123)456-7890`, and you want to extract `1234567890` from that?  Or is the idea that it finds the first number, so would result in `123` in my example?

Comment: It returns the full number

Answer (score 2):

One of the many ways it can be achieved is this:

```
$fileDownloadCount          =  (int) column_data_from_db;
$fileDownloadCount++;
```

The second line increments the value by 1.

Answer (score 1):

All suggestions lose the numeric type.

This seems to me a best practice:

```
function str2num($s){
// Returns a num or FALSE
    $return_value =  !is_numeric($s) ? false :               (intval($s)==floatval($s)) ? intval($s) :floatval($s);
    print "\nret=$return_value type=".gettype($return_value)."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Get Only number from string
$string = "123 Hello Zahid";
$res = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $string);
echo $res."<br>";
//Result 123
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the unary operator (+). For instance:

```
$n1 = +'7';
$n2 = '2.34';
$n2 = +$n1;
```

var_dump($n1): int(7)
var_dump($n2): float(2.34)

Comment: it converts everything in number a letter becomes 0.

Answer (score 1):

Update for PHP 8:

There is a function called `intval()` that allows you to convert a string to a number.
You can read more on https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php

For example:

`intval("376")` would output `376`

or

`intval(376)` would output `376`

Answer (score 0):

PHP will do it for you within limits

```
<?php
   $str = "3.148";
   $num = $str;

   printf("%f\n", $num);
?>
```

Comment: I don't want to out put it. I want to convert it and save it in a variable.

Comment: This automagically converted it to a float. PHP's loose type conversion does it for you. Although it may not do what you expect so the other answers with explicit conversion may work better for you.

Comment: $str can contains '5' or '5.258' using printf("%f\n", $str) '5' will out put as 5.000000 (I want it as 5) for 5.280000 (I want it as 5.28) it contains more decimal points.

Comment: Re *"This automagically converted it to a float."* Not usefully. `$num = $str;` did not change the value at all, of course. And the printf prints something somewhere - so its still a string. This might be more obvious if you used `sprintf` instead! Nowhere in your answer is there a float value that can be extracted and used elsewhere. [Agreed that *internally* it was a float temporarily - but still is not an answer to the question. If OP wanted to *print* the original string, he could simply have done `printf("%s\n", $str)`.]

Answer (score 0):

You can just add 0 to your string, and you will convert it to number without losing initial original value. Try for example:

```
dd('0.3454545' + 0)
```

PHP will handle conversion for you, or as already suggested add + before your string.

Answer (score -2):

I got the question "say you were writing the built in function for casting an integer to a string in PHP, how would you write that function" in a programming interview. Here's a solution.

```
$nums = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"];
$int = 15939; 
$string = ""; 
while ($int) { 
    $string .= $nums[$int % 10]; 
    $int = (int)($int / 10); 
} 
$result = strrev($string);
```

Comment: Thank you for attempting to contribute to the Q&A. But, sorry, not what is being asked in the question. Your code converts an integer to a string. The question is about converting a string to an integer. The question is also not about how to write code to do something that can already be done using built-in features of the language.