# How to check the Datatype in php which is given in html textbox?

Tags: php, html, types

I have used

```
get_type($var)
```

But it always returns as string.. from the text box

```
echo "<input type='text' name='value'>";
```

Comment: are you getting the values via Get/Post?

Comment: `gettype()` you mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the documentation, it's `gettype($var)` not `get_type($var)`. Check the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php) for more.

Answer (score 5):

You will always get strings from HTTP requests - as technically their params are passed as strings.

If you want to check whether a param (or any given value, in fact) is a numeric string, use [**is_numeric**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) function:

```
var_dump(gettype('111'));          // 'string'
var_dump(is_int('111'));           // false - as it's a string, not an integer
var_dump(is_numeric('111'));       // true  - this string represents a number
var_dump(is_numeric('something')); // false - and this string doesn't
```

Answer (score 3):

The function `gettype()` should only be used to output the datatype of a variable. Testing for special datatypes – with this function – is not recommended, because the returns may change at some point. Instead, the functions `is_boolean($var)`, `is_string($var)`, `is_float($var)`, `is_array($var)`, `is_object($var)`, `is_resource($var)` and `is_null($var)` should be used.

For more details : https://stackhowto.com/how-do-you-determine-the-data-type-of-a-variable-in-php/

Answer (score 0):

take a look at all the `ctype` functions in [php](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ctype.php) you will find the functions you need to determine the type of a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gettype();` to check datatype of variable in php.
However, the value of the input element of HTML is always wrapped into the string.

To convert string into number or other datatypes, there are a few ways to do so:
you can see the solution for it here...
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8529678/10743165