# Check type of user input (PHP)

Tags: php

Hi I am quite new in PHP and I wanna know how can I check what type of variable the user entered

For example if the user entered a string return an error.Or if the user entered an integer redirect him to the next html page.

I think you got what I mean.Please help me :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check the Datatype in php which is given in html textbox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18267155/how-to-check-the-datatype-in-php-which-is-given-in-html-textbox)

Answer (score 2):

- [`gettype`](http://php.net/gettype)
- [`is_numeric`](http://php.net/is_numeric)

be aware:

```
var_dump(gettype('1')); // string
```

because

```
'1' !== 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$type = gettype($input);

    if($type == 'integer'){
    // redirect

    }
    else{
        echo "error";

    }
```

The `gettype() function` is used to get the type of a `variable`. for more info read http://www.w3resource.com/php/function-reference/gettype.php

**but** i suggest use `is_numeric()` instead of `gettype()`

```
$type = is_numeric($input);

        if($type){
        // redirect

        }
        else{
            echo "error";

        }
```

because  `gettype` treats `variable` in `single quotes` or `double quotes` as string so for `gettype` `'1'` is `string`  not `integer`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php). It allows you to test your input as you're describing.

Example assuming that you want to validate it's an int value:

```
<?php

$input = 'some string';

if (filter_var($input, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) === false) {
    // it's not an int value, return error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh so ok i used the (is_numeric();)function and it worked thanks to all of you !! :DD