# AJAX Post with Integers

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, sqlite, post

I am using AJAX to post to a highScores table in a sqlite database, the total of the high score has to be calculated by a query and retrieved back through the database. How can I send the score through AJAX to the PHP script as an integer so I can perform mathematical calculations on it? St the moment I cant seem to do anything with it because the value gets to the php script as a string.

Comment: Ever hear of typecasting?
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: In php try this `$num = (int) $_POST["yourIntegerAsString"];`. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529656/php-how-to-convert-string-to-number

Comment: I have tried to cast it with the use of (int) but still nothing happens

Comment: Remove the quotes in your query. `'$socre'` should be `$score` because it is an integar

Answer (score 1):

PHP is a loosely-typed language so you can easily cast the received value.
See the following answer for more information: [How do I convert a string to a number in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529656/php-how-to-convert-string-to-number)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php

or typecast

```
$something = (int) $var * 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you just remove the single quotes around your $score variable?

instead of:

```
$query = "UPDATE User SET Score = '$score' + Score WHERE Username = '$player'";
```

this:

```
$query = "UPDATE User SET Score = $score + Score WHERE Username = '$player'";
```

You do need to do your own sql-injections checks.

Otherwise you'll make it a string in your sql-query.

Comment: You don't know that he doesn't want the string '$score' as a part of the value being updated.