# How to print an entire array when third dimension is constant

Tags: php, arrays, 3d

How to print an entire array when one index is constant.

For understanding purposes I have made this array

```
$actionF = array(
    "enemyHlth" =>  array(array()),
    "enemyBlts" =>  array(array())
);
```

with input

```
3 2 1
1 2 3
3 2 1
1 2 3
3 2 1
1 2 3
```

*The array structure is supposed to store top three rows under a 3D array with
3rd dimension is just a constant "Enemy Health" while the bottom three in 3D
array with same for 3rd dimension "Enemy Bullets". And both these two 3D arrays are stored in a single array called ActionF*

Now when I try to print it

```
for($level=0;$level<$n;$level++){  
    $actionF["enemyHlth"] = array ( $level =>  fscanf($_fp,"%d\t%d\t%d\n")
                                    );            
}

for($bullets = 0;$bullets<$m; $bullets++){  
    $actionF["enemyBlts"] = array ( $bullets => fscanf($_fp,"%d\t%d\t%d\n")
                                    );           
}
print_r($actionF);
```

Output

```
3 2 1
```

I think it is printing the last index of above I/P. How to make
 a 2D array when third dimension is just a constant or is there something else am I missing?

Comment: I think that the way you're reading the data is bad. Try this: instead of those two **for** statements use this to display the whole array: `print_r($actionF);`  I think you'll see the array does not contain what you expect, because you haven't read the file correctly. I could try helping you write the correct code but I'm not sure what you want to achieve. What should **$actionF["enemyHlth"]** and **$actionF["enemyBlts"]** contain at the end, assuming everything works well? Also, what are **$n** and **$m**? By the way, you're also missing a *$* in front of *n* here: *$bullets<n*

Comment: Its a challenge type program from Hacker's Rank. You can find it 
"A Super Hero"
by ma5termind

Comment: You're not adding to the `enemyHlth` element each time through the first loop, you're simply overwriting it. If you want to add to an array, it should be either `$actionF["enemyHlth"][] = new element;` or `$actionF["enemyHlth"][$key] = new element;` depending on whether you're creating an indexed or associative array. Your question doesn't say what the array is supposed to look like.

Comment: Yes I changed them to this `fscanf($_fp,"%d\t%d\t%d\n")` now it is at least reading the line but it is only reading last line.

Comment: I tried print_r at first it showed something which made no sense but now it is initializing the 2 index of level and bullets correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote your code and I think it works well like this:

First, the input:

```
$actionF = array(
        "enemyHlth" =>  array(),
        "enemyBlts" =>  array()
        );

for($level=0;$level<$n;$level++){

    $line = fgets($_fp);

    $processed = explode(" ", $line);

    if ($line != false) {
        $actionF["enemyHlth"][$level] = $processed;
    }

}

for($bullets = 0;$bullets<$m; $bullets++){  

    $line = fgets($_fp);

    $processed = explode(" ", $line);

    if ($line != false) {
         $actionF["enemyBlts"][$bullets] = $processed;           
    }
}
```

And here's the output:

```
for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++){
    for($j=0;$j<$m;$j++){
        print $actionF["enemyHlth"][$i][$j];
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Comment: You have used fgets but it returns a string rather than a integer which is required.

Comment: Would like to know the purpose why you are checking the line since the input is already defined in proper format?

Comment: PHP will auto-cast to integers strings that look like integers. You can write this code: `<?php

$x = "12";

$x = $x + 5;

echo $x; 


?>` and it will output 17. So it's ok if they are strings. If you want to be extra safe you can force cast them to integer. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529656/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-a-number-in-php . Regarding your second question, I'm checking the line out of habit. In real-life programming you can't ever trust the input, you must check it. In your case you can remove the test because you can be sure the input is correct.