# syntax error in converting varchar into int

Tags: php

I am getting this error

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(int) , (int)' at line 2
```

I followed up this answer on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529656/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-a-number-in-php)

I am getting base and limit as string , i want to convert them into int. This is my code

```
$category = $_POST['category'];
$base= $_POST['base'];
$limit= $_POST['limit'];

$sql = "SELECT id, name, url
FROM OBJECTS where CATEGORY='$category' limit (int)$base , (int)$limit";
```

Comment: PHP wont interpolate that in a quoted string, you should do this `{(int)$base}` with brackets, or `".(int)$base."`

Comment: As others have said, you're trying to use the PHP method of casting in a mySQL statement. mySQL doesn't understand that.  Either cast it first in PHP and then put it into the SQL statement or use mySQL's cast operators.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix `{(int)$base}` will not work, because `{` must be followed by `$` in order for PHP to place variable there.

Comment: @Justinas - you may be right, I'm on the right track though. I'll update my answer.  By the way thanks, I do recall that now that you mention it.

Comment: I like doing my codes in the SQL statement as it allows me to be modular with the POSTs, all the other answers are good takes too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP variable interpolation will not fill that in when in a string.

You need to do it like this

```
 $sql = "SELECT id, name, url FROM OBJECTS where CATEGORY='$category' limit ".(int)$base." , ".(int)$limit;
```

Interpolation only works on variables ( or things that start with the $ ) such as accessing a class ( which is in a variable ) so things like this

```
   echo "self::$STATIC";
```

will look for `$STATIC` as a variable.  Essentially you are putting this if $v = 1

```
  "(int)$v" becomes "(int)1"
```

And subsequently, MySql looks at `(int)1` as a string and blows up.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to cast it. What you are doing now is PHP casting. you will have to cast it in the SQL statement.

```
$category = $_POST['category'];
$base= $_POST['base'];
$limit= $_POST['limit'];

$sql = "SELECT id, name, url
FROM OBJECTS where CATEGORY='$category' limit CAST($base AS UNSIGNED) , CAST($limit AS UNSIGNED)";
```

Answer (score 3):

Use casting like this,

```
$category = $_POST['category'];
$base= intval($_POST['base']);
$limit= intval($_POST['limit']);
//OR
/*
 $base= (int)($_POST['base'];
 $limit= (int)($_POST['limit'];
*/

$sql = "SELECT `id`, `name`, `url`
FROM `OBJECTS` where CATEGORY='$category' limit $base ,$limit";
```

Answer (score 2):

MySql does not have type cast in PHP manner. So `(int)$base` is wrong syntax.

First type cast, than place to query:

```
$base = intval($base);
$limit = intval($limit);

$sql = "SELECT id, name, url FROM OBJECTS where CATEGORY = '{$category}' limit {$base}, {$limit}";
```

---

Consider using prepared statements instead of placing variables directly to query and not escaping them.

Answer (score 1):

use intval in php...ref.link `http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php`

```
$category = $_POST['category'];
$base= intval($_POST['base']);
$limit= intval($_POST['limit']);

$sql = "SELECT id, name, url
FROM OBJECTS where CATEGORY='$category' limit $base , $limit";
```