# array conversion removing index

Tags: php, codeigniter

Below function i.e getBooksInsertedCount code gives output like this

```
  array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

getBooksInsertedCount

```
function getBooksInsertedCount()
{  
  $this->load->database();    
  $query = "SELECT count(book_id) as count,date(created_date) as cdate FROM `bookdetails` WHERE  (created_date BETWEEN '2018-06-25' AND '2018-06-28') GROUP by created_date order by created_date asc";
  $result = $this->db->query($query);
 $ret = array();

   foreach ($result->result_array() as $row ) {
            $ret[] = $row['count'];
   } 
     return $ret;
  }
```

Expected output(Note here: [0]=>  string(1) is removed)

```
array(1, 2, 1);
```

Comment: The current output you posted and the expected output are the same.

Comment: just cast to int on the line `$ret[] = $row['count'];`

Comment: And what's the difference, except `int` and `string` types?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert a string to a number in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529656/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-a-number-in-php)

Comment: every array has indexes : if you var_dump `$a = [1,2,3]` it will give you `array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  int(3)
}
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [cast](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting) the value (type juggling).

Change,

```
$ret[] = $row['count'];
```

To,

```
$ret[] = (int) $row['count'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your expected output matches the current output, apart from the type (string VS int)

If I understand your question correctly, you'd like to remove the array indexes.

When creating an array like this `array('first', 'second')`, every value is assigned an index based on it's position, it's not possible to remove this (would also make it very hard to select something you need from it).

So the above example actually matches `array(0 => 'first', 1 => 'second')`.