# Parse value as an integer with PHP?

Tags: php

I'm trying to return a max value from my table.

```
$link = new PDO('mysql:dbname='.$dbname.';host='.$dbhost.';charset=utf8',$dbuser, $dbpass ) or die();
$gid = $link->prepare("SELECT MAX(level) as level FROM users");
$gid->execute();
$maxLevelRes = $gid->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$maxLevelVal = $maxLevelRes['level']; 
$maxLevel = ++$maxLevelRes;
```

I want `$maxLevel` to be the result of my `$maxLevelVal` + 1, it currently outputs...

> Array

Can anybody tell me why the value in my table is an integer ?

Comment: Have you tried your last line being `$maxLevel = $maxLevelVal + 1;`.  `$maxLevelRes` is a record which will be an array.

Comment: yes, that just returns 1 @NigelRen

Comment: Read your question again. The error is in front of you. You said *"I want `$maxLevel` to be the result of my `$maxLevelVal + 1`"* but you put something else in `$maxLevel` in the code.

Comment: You soudl try `$maxLevel =$maxLevelRes['level'] + 1 `. If it didn't work, please do `var_dump($maxLevelRes)` and show us the result ty

Comment: You're right, thanks @axiac

Comment: `$maxLevel = ++$maxLevelVal;` is ambiguous. Maybe it has the expected outcome but it is confusing for the reader. What happen first? The pre-increment (`++`) or the assignment (`=`)? It is much clear to express it as `$maxLevel = $maxLevelVal + 1;`. If you also need to increment `$maxLevelVal` then you can do it in a separate statement (either `$maxLevelVal += 1;` or `$maxLevelVal ++;`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[fetch](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) with the flag of `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` returns an `array` of the columns returned:

> PDO::FETCH_ASSOC: returns an array indexed by column name as returned in your result set

you should use [fetchColumn](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) to return a value of the column rather than get the array.

You'd have to use (in your current code) `$maxLevelRes['level']` to get your data.

Comment: @Liam no worries :)

Answer (score -1):

**Try this:**

```
$maxLevelVal = $maxLevelRes['level']; 
$maxLevel = ++$maxLevelVal;
```

For more: [How do I convert a string to a number in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529656/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-a-number-in-php/8529687)