# how to display only int value from php string variable?

Tags: php

Iam a beginner of PHP .
My question is soo small.

Suppose , my current value is 250 Taka.
or 
BDT 250 /- 

How can i show only price : 250 ?

My code :

```
$maxprice= "250 Taka.";
<td style="width: 20%;"><?php echo $maxprice; ?></td>
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert a string to a number in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529656/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-a-number-in-php)

Comment: `(int)$maxprice`.

Comment: @ObsidianAge That wouldn't work for the second example

Comment: its not working !!

Comment: Probably a better duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278296/extract-numbers-from-a-string

Comment: `preg_replace('/[^\d]+/', '', $str)` ~ replace all non-number values in a string.  [Example](https://regex101.com/r/keAxU8/1)

Comment: @PatrickQ Thanks !!! problem is solved now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract numbers from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278296/extract-numbers-from-a-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `preg_replace` and replace everything not a digit

```
$maxprice = preg_replace('/[^\d]+/', '', $maxprice);
```

[For Example](https://regex101.com/r/keAxU8/1)

The Regx is pretty simple:

- `[^...]+` anything not in character set One or more times
- `\d` any digit 0-9

So it replaces anything that is not 0-9.

Enjoy