# Convert VueJS output from String to Int in PHP

Tags: php, vue.js

So I outputed a result from `{{blogs.totalPage}}`.This `{{blogs.totalPage}}` has a value of `5`. Then this value, I added it to my while loop. But the while loop is not working and the ouput is `0` because the outputed value 5 is String not Int.

```
<?php
$cnt = 0;

$pageTotal = "'{{blogs.totalPage}}'";

while($cnt<=$pageTotal){
echo "Number: ".$cnt
$cnt++;
}
```

Then I tried adding `(int)`

```
<?php
$cnt = 0;

$pageTotal = (int)"'{{blogs.totalPage}}'";
while($cnt<=$pageTotal){
echo "Number: ".$cnt
$cnt++;
}
```

Can you help me to convert this String into Int to make my while loop working?
Thanks

Let me add, the reason why I know it is string and has an output of 5, I tried to `var_dump($pageTotal)` and the output is `string(21) "'5'"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert a string to a number in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529656/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-a-number-in-php)

Comment: I don't see from your question how `"'{{blogs.totalPage}}'"` gets converted to a value of "5". Are you sure $pageTotal is actually "5" or are you assuming that it should be?

Comment: @DRogueRonin It is, I var dump it, the output is `string(21) "'5'"`

Comment: @WillDaSilva This is not a Possible duplicate, this is VueJS + PHP, and as you can see I already tried (int). Please read the question properly before marking it as duplicate.

Comment: @ICGDEVS Have you tried the other methods in the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8529678/5946921

Comment: Did you try just removing the single quotes around `{{blogs.totalPage}}` ?

Comment: @DRogueRonin it will no longer works if I removed that, the 5 will become 0.

Comment: @WillDaSilva, I tried the link you gave, the intval(), but sadly, it didnt work also. the output became 0 which is should be 5.

Comment: Are you using Vue and PHP in the same page (file)? If so, I'm curious as to why?