# remove quotation mark in ajax response

Tags: javascript, ajax

the response comes back as `"4"` instead of just `4`

I tried changing it to .done(function(data)) but still has the same result

```
                        $.ajax({
                                url: "../api/ajax/addToCart.php",
                                type: "post",
                                data: data
                            })
                            .done(function(response) {
                                 // alert(response);
                                 $('#cart_counter').html(response);
                                // console.log(JSON.parse(response));
                                getCart();
                                // console.log(response);
                            });
```

the ajax is taking the response from this page
addToCart.php

```
$sql1 = 'DELETE FROM temp_cart WHERE item_id = "'  . $item_id . '" AND temp_id = "' . $temp_id . '"';
            $result = $conn->query($sql1);
            {
                $sql2 = 'INSERT INTO temp_cart(temp_id, temp_name, temp_number, item_name, item_price, item_quantity, item_total, item_pic, item_id, date_expiry) VALUES ("' . $temp_id . '", "' . $temp_name . '", "' . $temp_number . '", "' . $item_name . '", "' . $item_price . '", "' . $item_quantity . '", "' . $total_row . '", "' . $item_pic . '", "' . $item_id . '", "' . $date_expiry . '" )';
                $result = $conn->query($sql2);

                    {
                        $sql = "SELECT count(item_quantity) as count_quantity FROM temp_cart WHERE temp_id='$temp_id'";
                        $resultb = $conn->query($sql);
                        while($rowb = $resultb->fetch_assoc())
                            {
                               $cart_counter=$rowb['count_quantity'];
                               echo json_encode($cart_counter);
                            }
                    }
            }
```

Comment: What are you sending from the server?  Sounds like an extra stringify() somewhere.

Comment: @zipzit updated the question, please have a look

Comment: I’m thinking server side php. Where do you send the $cart_ quantity back to client as a response?  json_encode ??

Comment: @zipzit yes, json_encode

Comment: This is [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529656/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-a-number-in-php/8529687) to my question.

Answer (score 1):

The data not really JSON format, but a number that is being stringified when you pass it back as JSON so it ends up a string. Just parse the string into a number as needed:

```
 $('#cart_counter').html(parseInt(response));
```

```js
let counter = 4;
let json = JSON.stringify(counter);

console.log(json, `is a ${typeof json}`);

console.log(`...now a ${typeof parseInt(json)}`);

document.querySelector('#target').innerHTML = parseInt(json);
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```

Comment: it is now displaying nothing. no error can be seen in console

Comment: can you please `console.log(response, typeof response);`

Comment: it says


"8" string

Comment: just `8` or does it have all those backticks - I assume that's just the comment formatting? Can you update to `console.log(parseInt(response), typeof parseInt(response))`

Comment: it says "8" with the quotations

Comment: it now says "number" with the quotations

Comment: but it still displays with the quotation marks on my element

Comment: See the updated example above, you must be missing a step parsing before you set the value.

Comment: what I did was I removed the 2 console lines and I made it like let counter = response;

Comment: it displays Nan in the element

Comment: It's difficult to determine further without seeing all the code. But, you have the core principles. If you have a string and need to cast it to do further operations on it, then use parseInt. It sounds like something else is trying to access the value.

Comment: I upvoted you for the time and effort, thank you so much

Comment: What was it issue?

Comment: I've tried converting it in the other page to no avail. I should have converted it to int in my addToCart.php before assigning it to json_encode. and when I did, it returned as 8 instead of "8"