# How to convert string number to int number using php

Tags: php

I got problem why is it happen when I convert the number of ROUND(4.9813200498132,1) in PhpMyAdmin it result 5.0 then when i try to convert the value in php it result 5 only. how to make the result 5.0 to the php side.? is it need to convert the string number to int number? to understand well i will share to you guys the sample equation that i create.

**Equation in php:**

```
$first_wtd_item_first_option =  str_replace( ',', '', $high_item_d_wtd_data->total_qty );
$first_wtd_item_second_option = str_replace( ',', '', $high_item_a_wtd_data->total_qty );
$first_wtd_item_third_option =  str_replace( ',', '', $high_item_b_wtd_data->total_qty );

$first_wtd_item_computation1 = $first_wtd_item_second_option + $first_wtd_item_third_option;
$first_wtd_item_computation2 = ($first_wtd_item_first_option / $first_wtd_item_computation1);
$first_wtd_item_computation3 = $first_wtd_item_computation2 * 100;
$first_wtd_item_final_result = (round($first_wtd_item_computation3,1).'%');
```

**Output:**

[image: rounded]

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert a string to a number in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529656/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-a-number-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **multiple with 10**, not with 100, also you can use [number_format()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

```
$first_wtd_item_first_option =  str_replace( ',', '', $number);
$first_wtd_item_second_option = str_replace( ',', '', $number);
$first_wtd_item_third_option =  str_replace( ',', '', $number);

$first_wtd_item_computation1 = $first_wtd_item_second_option + $first_wtd_item_third_option;
$first_wtd_item_computation2 = ($first_wtd_item_first_option / $first_wtd_item_computation1);
$first_wtd_item_computation3 = number_format((float) $first_wtd_item_computation2 * 10, 1, '.', '');
$first_wtd_item_final_result = $first_wtd_item_computation3.'%';
```

**Result:**

5.0%

Comment: I guess @Morgan you didn't understand my question.  what i mean for that. why the output is 5%, is it possible to make the 5% to 5.0%?

Answer (score 1):

you can use [number_format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

```
$first_wtd_item_final_result = (number_format(round($first_wtd_item_computation3,1), 1).'%');
```