# Best way to convert string[which is basically a comma seprated number] to an integer in PHP

Tags: php, string, numbers, integer

I have a value like `12,25,246`
I want to get `1225246` (must be an integer)

How can I do that?

I have searched a lot but there are direct answer like converting string to integer but not like this actually these both are like integer

I have tried php formate_number but it did not worked.

Comment: It already answered, You will get it in more details over there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529656/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-a-number-in-php

Comment: It's not the same. @Rajon

Comment: @Rajon The question is slightly different than the one you linked. Here the value has multiple commas and is not in a common numerical format.

Comment: Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. Give us a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: It is in JavaScript @MarkusZeller

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a combination of [`intval()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) and [`str_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to do this.

Example:

```
$value = '12,25,246';
var_dump(intval(str_replace(',','',$value)));
// Yields: "int(1225246)"
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/07ad164bd8785d7b69e73d8c86f0d36b82687214)

Answer (score 1):

```
$number = (int)str_replace(',', '', '12,25,246');
```

here is it