# php sees a variable but cannot handle with it

Tags: javascript, php

trying to get window width on server side

```
$w = "<script>document.write(screen.width);</script>";
echo $w;  // 1600
echo '<br>' . gettype($w); // string
```

now I need an integer instead the string
tried a lot of ways from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529656/)

for example

```
$w = intval($w);  
$w = (int) $w; 
settype($w, "integer"); 

echo $w;  // 0
echo '<br>' . gettype($w);  // integer
```

so result is allways `0` and `integer`

how to explain - php sees the variable but cannot handle with it ?
and how can I get `1600-integer`

Comment: Not at all, because $w is a string and will parse to 0. PHP does not execute JavaScript, the browser does. But, you could run JS via https://www.php.net/manual/de/class.v8js.php which will not give a window width, because it runs on server, not on client.

Comment: @MarkusZeller - `echo $w` is a server side, isn't it ?

Comment: All PHP code is server side. What is echoed will be displayed/run in STDOUT saying browser / terminal.

Comment: If you want to send data from browser to server you can use AJAX.

Comment: if `echo $w` can be run - what is the problem with `$w = intval($w);` ? What is the difference between the two ?

Comment: `$w` is a JS string, containing `<script>document.write(screen.width);</script>`. The `1600` is displayed by the browser by executing the script. Use `var_dump($w)` or view the raw page source and you will see this.

Comment: @user3783243 - so php can see a js string - and can detect a datatype of it - but cannot convert it ? That is what is strange

Comment: "_so php can see a js string_" No it can't

Comment: @provance What do you mean "see"? You wrote the JS so PHP has it.

Comment: @brombeer - executing `echo $w` and  `gettype($w)` should means - it see it - isn;t it ?

Comment: @provance Run `echo htmlspecialchars($w);` hopefully that clarifies it.

Comment: No, other users already said so. Please read the linked article [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming). Did you try `var_dump($w)` as suggested?

Comment: @user3783243 - but that is my question - why some works - for example `echo` and `gettype` and some doesn't work

Comment: Also already mentioned multiple times. `echo` and `gettype` DO NOT WORK as you think. `echo` prints out the javascript which in turn prints `1600` to the document - on the client side - PHP knows nothing about the client. If `$w` would hold the value `1600` its type would not be `string` but `integer`

Comment: `echo` sends it to the browser, the browser then renders it. `gettype` casts it as it is. It has been said multiple times already. `<script>document.write(screen.width);</script>` is not an integer, it is a string. A browser will process that to get the width and give an integer.

Comment: @user3783243 - I see now, in page source code there is no `1600` but the string `<script...`  Excuse... and thanks a lot

Comment: Exactly, that's what we have been trying to explain, glad you get it now :-)